# Bootsatrap navbar for gatsby project

Tags: sass, navbar, gatsby

I want to use bootstrap (v.5) navbar for a Gatsby project. In principle, it is possible to load components that only belong to the navbar. However, I can't find any information about which components belong to the navbar.

So far these I have these imports but not yet working unfortunately:
global.scss

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_nav";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_navbar";
```

Has anyone done this before? Do you know which components need to be imported to make it work?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where are you importing the `global.scss`

Comment: I importing it to gatsby-browser.js. Shouldn't it be here? Thank you for dealing with my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I importing it to `gatsby-browser.js`. Shouldn't it be here?

Yes, that's one option. As well as importing it in the `Layout` component as the [Standard Styling with Global CSS Files](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/global-css/) suggests.

The problem I guess is the path you're using. From the `gatsby-browser.js` there's no `../..` path hence the route and the asset is broken.

Try playing around with the path but I bet you can do directly something like:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/_nav";
@import "bootstrap/scss/_navbar";
```

Note that `./` should also work in the same way so try playing around with the relativity of the paths.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately the first version doesn't work but I'm looking for a solution in this direction and will try.